# Fscanf Seg Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I keep getting a segmentation fault with this code that I am trying to get to print the first 6 words of the dictionary. I'm pretty sure I'm using fscanf incorrectly but I'm not sure how/why...

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* enc[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {  
        printf("Improper command-line arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *Dict;
    Dict = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");

    if (Dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open dictionary");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* full = enc[1];
    char* salt[2];

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        salt[i] = &full[i];
    }

    char* key[50];

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        fscanf(Dict, "%s", *key);
        printf("%s", *key);
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's your question? "Here's a wall of code, guess what it's supposed to do and debug it for me" is not a question.

Comment: It's supposed to print the first 6 words of the dictionary. And I'm having a problem with the for loop at the end, it's causing a segmentation fault.

Comment: Lean how to use your IDE's debugger.  Look at this line - fscanf(Dict, "%s", *key);

Answer (score 1):

C strings are either a character array: `char name[10]`, or pointer-to-char (which points to a valid range of memory): `char* name`.

What you have here is an array of 50 pointers to characters (or strings):

```
char* key[50];

for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    fscanf(Dict, "%s", *key);
    printf("%s", *key);
}
```

`key` is probably intended to be a 50-character C string buffer:

```
char key[50];

for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    fscanf(Dict, "%s", key);
    printf("%s", key);
}
```